# mysql storing subquery in column and performing where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

i am performing a sub query in mysql which is like

```
select col1, col2 , (select col3 from table2) as 'data'
from table1 
where not data is null
```

how should i get data in where clause. IS it POSSIBLE

Comment: Your current query probably won't work because the subquery in the select clause will return more than one record.  Maybe you should show us sample data and desired output.

Comment: no it has only 1 row

Comment: Even so, your `WHERE` clause does not make sense.  What logic do you actually want there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       select col1, col2 , (select col3 from table2) as 'data'
       from table1 
)t
WHERE data IS NOT NULL
```

As you see there I have created on derived table `t` for your query, now result of your query is treated as Table(temp table) and having columns as col1,col2 and **col3**, Using this result set we can able to access col3 in where clause .

**Note -** assuming that `select col3 from table2` returns single value as per OP's comments

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: have you tried exact query since I already used alias --see at `t`

Comment: Yes : Updated Ans

Answer (score 0):

Use `cross join`:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3 as data
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select col3 from table2) t2
where t2.col3 is not null;
```